# Debconf got a corrupted perl script. How to reinstall it?

Tags: apt, debconf

I got some power issues at home and got a bunch of files in my computer corrupted. I could fix most of them, but one that's bugging me is a debconf script. Everytime I try to install something I get this:

```
Configuring php5-curl (5.4.9-ubuntu2.4) ...
Attempt to access disallowed key '�png' in a restricted hash at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 43, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 1.
dpkg: error processing php5-curl (--configure):
 sub-process script post-installation returned error state code 255
```

I searched a little bit that script (Config.pm) but found nothing strange, what makes me think it's something it reads or includes - but my perl knowledge is null and I have no idea how to fix that manually.

Is it possible to reinstall debconf and make that work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to download a random deb to install, and the graphical interface said there could be a error with my `sources.list`. I grep'd the `/etc/apt` folder instead of the perl scripts and found a PNG disguised as a sources file in `sources.list.d`. In the end, the problem wasn't the scripts but what they read from :P

Also, there was another of those bad PNGs itself in `/etc/debconf.conf`, which was probably the root of all problems. I found that by using the same method of outputting the buggy file - but in a healthy machine, so I had text strings to grep, found the complete file and copied it on top of that PNG.

Comment: well, that's interesting, because `dpkg` does not need any `apt` `configs`.

Comment: actually, I still found another png trash. fiddling with perl I could regenerate the image and found it to be the linux mint logo. hahaha now I'm working out a way to find where that image is located :/

Comment: I just wonder how this is possible :-)

Comment: when you discover, please, tell me! hahaha
there's also some trash in some file vi reads before opening, and the same with bash. see: http://i.imgur.com/RxeHw8x.png & http://i.imgur.com/HE81ZFg.png

Comment: edited the answer to explain where the second PNG were, @bersch ;)

Comment: yes, that makes sense. I looked at the code and the error belongs to parsing of the config file. This is very uncommon situation which can never occur (almost :-)